# DataGridRow.IsSelected is set and I dont know why

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Hello this is my problem:

I got two styles defined in the resources for DataGridRow and DataGridCell:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I basically want a row to be highlighted blue when user selects it.

I got a `MessageWrapper` and a `SignalWrapper` class. Each `MessageWrapper` has a list of `SignalWrappers` (which can be empty sometimes). So the first DataGrid is to display all `MessageWrappers`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="messageGrid"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Margin="3"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBusWrapper.MessageWrappers}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBusWrapper.SelectedMessageWrapper}"
                          attachedProperties:SelectingItemAttachedProperty.SelectingItem="{Binding SelectedBusWrapper.MessageWrapperToScrollIntoView,
                                                                                                   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                                                                   Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Filter">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox MaxWidth="15"
                                              MaxHeight="15"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding Filter}"
                                              Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="9*"
                                            Binding="{Binding Message.Name}"
                                            Header="Name" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="9*"
                                            Binding="{Binding HexId}"
                                            Header="Id" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="11*"
                                            Binding="{Binding Message.Sender}"
                                            Header="Sender" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Each Row of this `DataGrid` has a `CheckBox` column. If no `CheckBox` at all is checked then all `SignalWrappers` are displayed in second `DataGrid`. If one or more are checked, then only the `SignalWrappers` of the checkec `MessageWrappers` should be displayed. Here the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
                          Margin="3"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBusWrapper.SelectedSignalWrappers}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBusWrapper.SelectedSignalWrapper}"
                          SelectionMode="Extended">
                    <DataGrid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.Resources>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseDoubleClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Filter">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox MaxWidth="15"
                                              MaxHeight="15"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                              IsChecked="{Binding Filter}"
                                              Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="6*"
                                            Binding="{Binding Signal.Name}"
                                            Header="Name" />
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Value">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox MinWidth="75"
                                              IsEditable="True"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding Signal.Values.Values}"
                                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue,
                                                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                                                     Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Now if the user selects one or more message(s) in the first `DataGrid` the signals of those messages should be highlighted in the second. If the user selects a signal in the second, the parent message should be highlighted in the first `DataGrid`.

Bound Property of `MessageWrapper` class:

```
public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected == value) {
                return;
            }
            isSelected = value;

            foreach (var item in SignalWrappers) {
                item.IsSelected = value;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
```

Bound Property of `SignalWrapper` class:

```
public bool IsSelected
    {
        get 
        {
            return isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected == value) {
                return;
            }
            isSelected = value;

            ParentMessageWrapper.IsSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
```

Now I have an odd behavoir I cannot understand:

When I check the first `CheckBox` in the first `DataGrid`:

The message gets highlighted, the second `DataGrid` shows only the signals of that message and highlights them. This is correct so far.
If I now check a second message it highlights both rows and all signals of those rows. While debugging i noticed what happens is that the first `MessageWrappers` `IsSelected`flag gets set to false, and all its signals flag gets set to false, which is correct. Afterwards the second `MessageWrappers` flag gets set to true and all its signals flag gets set to true, which is correct too.
And afterwards for a reason I cannot understand a signal of the first `MessageWrapper` `IsSelected` flag is set to true, this will set the `MessageWrappers` flag to true and this will set the other signals flag to true.

Note: If I check the third `CheckBox` everything is working as expected again.

Can anybody understand why this is? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you have many loops when setting `IsSelected` in `SingleWrapper` because it set `ParentMessageWrapper.IsSelected = value;` which will return to set `IsSelected` in `SingleWrapper` and so on.

i suppose to make Method in `SingleWrapper` Like this:

```
public SetIsSelected(bool value)
{
    if (isSelected == value) {
        return;
    }
    isSelected = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
}
```

and change `item.IsSelected = value;` in `MessageWrapper` to `item.SetIsSelected(value)`